# Update an existing report in SalesForce using simple_salesforce package in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, salesforce

Given an existing report on SalesForce that I created, can I update the content of the report using simple_salesforce package in python?

```py
# A Pseudo code to get the expected result
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce


sf = Salesforce(username='my_user_name', 
                password='my_password',
                security_token='my_security_token')



export_url = "link to the report I want to change"

session = requests.Session()

response = requests.get(export_url, 
                       headers=sf.headers, 
                       cookies={'sid': sf.session_id})

# this part is pseudo-code, for instance, I want to change a column of the report, I change it and then upload the new version as the current report
response.update(response, data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're bit out of Simple's comfort zone. You don't manipulate data, you don't even use `restful` call for "normal" API operations. You just (ab)use simple's login functionality to get the session id and pretend you're a browser. So you can experiment with requests below in Postman for example and then go back to your Python program.

I wonder if you're overcomplicating it. Are you sure you absolutely need a report?

- Maybe it can be done with a normal SOQL query?
- There's proper [API for reports](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_intro.htm) and a way to [filter a report on the fly](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_filter_reportdata.htm). It won't save the changes to the report. But that API will return results as JSON, you probably coded your stuff around CSVs.
- If you need to actually save changes - there are proper Tooling API/Metadata API calls to fetch, modify and deploy back the [report definition as XML file](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_report.htm). Again - `simple` might not be best tool for the task, `sfdx` might fare better.
- I suspect you'll ignore all these and stick to faking a browser. Google around for "url hacking", for example [here](http://www.interactiveties.com/b_dynamic_report_part1.php). As it becomes more config than code issue - you can find some good stuff in dedicated sister site that has more admins than stackoverflow. For example https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/110219/799

Comment: great insight on subject. Can you recommend a library to write soql queries in python?

Comment: write queries in whatever you're comfortable with. Salesforce's Developer Console is crude but you don't install anything. Then there's semi-official https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php. My colleague recently shown me https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-inspector/aodjmnfhjibkcdimpodiifdjnnncaafh, pretty neat and has some autocomplete features. If you have sfdx and vscode - https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/soql/soql-builder